# Confirmation message when focus on tr row

Tags: jquery, focus, message, confirmation

I have a question about a focus function when a confirmation message is displayed, so how is possible to have focus background when I press on an action button that is displaying a confirmation message. In my example when I press the button, background focus remain selected on last tr selection how you can check on my example:
I want that when I press the button from a  row "n" the focus to be on background of that row.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebG9N/9/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something link this:

```
$('table.grid tbody  tr td').click(function () {
        var selected = $(this).parent();
        selected.focus();  //added focus
        $('table.grid> tbody > tr').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("selectedRow")) {
                $(this).removeClass("selectedRow");} });
        if (!selected.hasClass('selectedRow')) {
            selected.addClass("selectedRow");

        }});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I tested with your modified function and have exactly the same behavior :((  if you check my example and modify with your function will see that the focus is not added on background when press delete button from other line